# CountIF / Remove duplicate values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that has the headers

```
phone # | email | name
```

When I import incoming data, I want to delete the original entry and new entry if they are duplicate. To do so I am trying to use this formula

```
=IF(COUNTIF(F:H,Table1[@[Phone Number]:[Name]])=1,0,1)
```

Howevever it is returning the same value for duplicates and non duplicates. When I take out the range and just try based of one criteria (phone number) I am getting expected results

```
=IF(COUNTIF(F:H,Table1[@[Phone Number]])=1,0,1)
```

Does anybody know how I can modify this in order for the criteria to be all three columns?

New formula based off comments

```
IF(COUNTIFS(F:H,[@[Phone Number]],F:H,[@[Email Address]],F:H,[@[Name]])=1,0,1)
```

Edit2: The solution that worked

```
IF(COUNTIFS(F:F,[@[Phone Number]],G:G,[@[Email Address]],H:H,[@[Name]])=1,0,1)
```

Comment: check function COUNTIFS. The range criteria is ok `F:H`, but the criteria must be a single value, not another range. `Table1[@[Phone Number]]` is a value, but `Table1[@[Phone Number]:[Name]]` is a range. So you need to specify each criteria once, and each criteria needs its own criteria range.

Comment: I think I get it. @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns. I came up with a new formula but still getting same values for duplicate and non duplicate. Edited my post

Comment: Can you post a data example with your input and the expected output?

Comment: Also, the range criteria should be a single column, not `F:H` like I said before. Check https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842

Comment: That solved it!

Comment: Hi @user8876747 Please post you answer is what method you have solved it. So that others can understood and it will help them in future when they were trying for it.